# Customize session_start event parameters on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'd like to change the *session_start* event parameters (minimum session duration and session timeout duration) on iOS (Swift if possible).

I found a document ([link](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en&ref_topic=6317484)), but it redirects only on Android documentation ([1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#setMinimumSessionDuration(long)) and [2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#setSessionTimeoutDuration(long))) and I can't find the equivalent in the iOS documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Too late to give a reply, you must have already found the link. I was spending more time to find the link, posting it here as this might be helpful for people like me searching. I found Session configuration can only be done in Analytics class but unsure if there are other options too!

iOS session configuration - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasecore/api/reference/Classes/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration